# Pandas Python - Creating an indexed performance tracker

Tags: python, pandas, finance

It's my first time posting so thanks a million in advance for any solutions to my problem!

I am trying to create a function which takes fund_name as an argument and creates an indexed performance tally (starting at 100) in a new column within the fund_name df. The df input is similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8rK8.png).

and the desired output can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA7uL.png).

The code I have used is below, but results in the index beginning at zero rather than 100:

```
def test(fund_name):
   fund_name['Indexed_Performance'] = ''
   fund_name['Indexed_Performance'] = pd.to_numeric(fund_name['Indexed_Performance'])
   fund_name.loc[0, 'Indexed_Performance'] = fund_name.loc[0, 'Monthly_Performance']
   for i in range(1, len(fund_name)):
       if fund_name.loc[i, 'Indexed_Performance'] < 10:
           fund_name.loc[i, 'Indexed_Performance'] = 100 * (fund_name.loc[i, 'Monthly_Performance'] + 1)
       else:
           fund_name.loc[i, 'Indexed_Performance'] = fund_name.loc[i-1, 'Indexed_Performance'] * (fund_name.loc[i, 'Monthly_Performance'] + 1)
```

Thanks again in advance for any solutions to this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean exactly, especially in the `if` statement, but maybe it's as simple as this?

```py
import numpy as np

def test(df):
    perfs = 1 + df['Monthly_Performance']
    df['Indexed_Performance'] = np.cumprod(perfs) * 100  # Cumulative product of ratios
```

which outputs

```py
    Monthly_Performance  Indexed_Performance
0                 -0.05            95.000000
1                  0.10           104.500000
2                  0.02           106.590000
3                 -0.06           100.194600
4                  0.00           100.194600
5                 -0.04            96.186816
6                  0.07           102.919893
7                 -0.07            95.715501
8                 -0.01            94.758346
9                  0.07           101.391430
10                 0.10           111.530573
11                 0.07           119.337713
12                 0.06           126.497976
13                -0.03           122.703036
14                 0.10           134.973340
15                -0.04           129.574406
16                -0.03           125.687174
17                -0.06           118.145944
18                 0.06           125.234700
```

If not can you give more details about how you compute your performance index ?